# Copying Red Underline PopUp Error Message - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a shortcut key or view that would allow me to copy the red underlined popup error message in Android Studio?

[image: Example of popup error message]

Answer (score 3):

1. Click on the red line to move the cursor there
2. The error message will be shown in status bar at the bottom, right click on status bar and a little popup "copy" will be shown.

This will work on windows. Vote for [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65636#tab=Comments) to be fixed on Intellij IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

To work on Linux (Ubuntu). Here's what worked for me:

When you make the popup shows up, hold Alt+Shift and carefully select any amount of the text and press Ctrl+C.

You don't need to select all of the text, because it will always copy the whole message ignoring the selection.

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and Android Studio 3.5.2.